# GuzzleHttp \ Exception \ RequestException cURL error 52: Empty reply from server

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, mandrill, guzzle

Trying to send email with Laravel using Mandrill. I've set up a test API on Mandrill and have put the API key into the `services.php` config array, and set the driver to 'mandrill'. Here's how I'm sending the email:

```
    $data = array(
        'activation_code'     => $user->activation_code
    );

    Mail::send('emails.auth.activate', $data, function($message) use ($user)
    {
        $message->from('test@test.com', 'Test');

        $message->to($user->email);
    });
```

What could be causing the above error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First Receiver Email Address.

   $data = array(
           'activation_code'     => $user->activation_code,
   'email' => 'abc@xyx.com'
       );
2. Check your API Credential. Your API authentication may fail to send emails.